# Launching two functions with setInterval and having them start immediately with no delay

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to create a scenario where I have two variables (or more) both assigned to their own setInterval object and each setInterval object has a different function and a different millisecond value. The goal is to create a rhythm between the two by launching functions that play two different audio files repeatedly.

The current problem I've come across is this:

If one set interval is set to 1000 and the other is set to 500 each one doesn't *start* immediately. The millisecond delay is *part of the start time*. I want to know how to omit the delay on the start time so that both functions launch immediately but then they each keep there respective interval times.

The "logic" I've come up with so far is something along the lines of creating a function that immediately plays audio with no millisecond value and then have another function that is assigned to setInterval which begins playing x number of millisecond earlier on the next "beat" to make up the difference. I'm curious if the logic seems sound or if this is a problem in which a "conventional" javascript solution exist that I don't know about.It seems like there is an easier way.

I haven't begun coding yet albeit I didn't want to dig myself a hole before I have to if someone already has a fix for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I avoid setInterval. Instead, i use setTimeout with such a pattern:

```
function someThing() {
    // do something ...
    setTimeout(someThing, 2000);
    // or do something after setting the timeout ...
}

// either delay the start:
// setTimeout(someThing, 1000);
// or start right away
someThing()
```

But if you really want to use setInterval then a similar pattern works:

```
function someThing(firstTime) {
    if (firstTime === true) {
        console.log('setting interval for someThing');
        setInterval(someThing, 1000);
    }

    console.log('someThing called');
}
someThing(true);
```